# How would one go about styling HTML elements in a CSS file for mobile viewport

Tags: html, css

I don't really understand a proper way to ask this, sorry in advance if I lead to confusion.

I need to style HTML elements on my CSS page for mobile viewports and then add a comment where the mobile styles begin. From what I gathered from my book, styling the elements is just changing the fixed sizes to relative sizes, but the second part of the question leads me to believe that I need a whole new set of styles for each element, so how would I have one style for my main for normal view, and then a new style for main for mobile viewport?

Sorry yet again for horrible wording, and I'm not asking for any coding done, just some direction.

Comment: mediaqueries ?? indeed your question is not clear and there no code either that could show your issue/trouble :(

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you want to create a webpage that's also mobile friendly.

[Twitter Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) is the most popular framework for achieving this, and is used in almost every new web application.

I would suggest watching some [Bootstrap tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gqOEoUR5RHg) on this. Derek Banas has really good introductory tutorials to show you how different languages/frameworks interact.

I wouldn't recommend him for an in depth tutorial on understanding all the in-and-outs of the topics of his video, but he's amazing at showing what the particular topic of the video is excellent at.

Answer (score 1):

Use media queries! [Here is the MDN page on them](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)

For example, this will make all `h1`s red if the viewport is smaller than `600px`

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    h1 {
        color: red;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't much clear.

Consider using *media queries* in CSS to work with your viewport.

See: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

Maybe you like to use some CSS Frameworks to help you, like [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com) ou [Materialize](http://materializecss.com/).

I recommend Bootstrap because learning is easier than Materialize.